# Xcode & iOS - Create Plugins?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, interface-builder

Is it possible to create custom UIViews that can be used as plugins on interface builder?
So I can drag and drop them on interface bulder and see how the actual view looks like without havig to run the code to see the view.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It was possible to create plugins for older versions of Interface Builder, but I don't believe it's currently possible in Xcode 4. If you'd like that feature, the best thing to do is to [file a bug report with Apple](http://bugreport.apple.com) asking for it.

Comment: Plug-ins for Cocoa Touch was never supported even before Xcode 4, only for Cocoa.

Comment: That's true, but at this point they're not supported for *anything*. Apple engineers have often said that they use bug reports to help them prioritize new features, so it's always good to file one to register your wishes.

Answer (score 2):

No, Interface Plug-ins is not yet supported by Xcode 4, never was for iOS on older Xcode 3.x.

File a feature request at http://bugreport.apple.com to put more pressure on this issue.